# Select min returns empty row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Query

```
select min Price, min year from tblProduct
```

returns empty ("") results. I only want results in numbers. How do I do that?

Example:

```
tblProduct
Price   Year

1000    2008
2000    2009
500  2001
        2005
200  2000
```

The result is Price "", year 2000. I want the result to be Price 200, year 2000

Comment: What version of SQL are you using (ie. MySQL, SQL Server, etc.)?

Comment: I'm guessing you have price defined as a sting field. Define it as a numerical field and use mulls to indicate no value rather than an empty string.

Comment: SQL Server, I dont want an empty value. I want the min value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, what is your RDBMS? For the ones I tried (MySQL and PostgreSQL), MIN ignores NULL.

Therefore, I assume your column is of type varchar or text. Which doesn't make sense for a price, so I suggest that you change it to a numeric type.

If you don't want to, then I'd use something like this :

```
SELECT MIN(price), MIN(year)
FROM tblProduct
WHERE price <> ''
```

Which would return (200, 2000). But really, it doesn't make sense. You want to use a numeric type and you want to use NULL instead of using an empty string.

Answer (score 3):

This will give the minimum value for each year

```
Select min(p.price) , year
  from 
    tblProduct p 
  WHERE p.price <> ''
  Group by 
      p.year
```

This will give you the year and price for the min Price.

This may result in multiple rows when more than one year has the min price

```
Select p.year, p.price from 
tblProduct p inner join 
    (Select min (Price) price
    from tblProduct where price is not null) minP
on p.price = minp.Price
```

Comment: MIN ignores NULL, your first answer was probably better (assuming Price is varchar or text). Edit: Woah, you make everything harder, OP seems to want the minimum price AND the minimum year, not necessarily the year related to the minimum price.

Comment: @Vincent. You're right I'm probably making bad assumptions. Its not clear to me what is wanted. Probably the first one.

Comment: exactly, not necessarily the year related to the minimum price. I cant get it to work WHERE p.price <> "" I get this error. An object or column is missing or empty.

Comment: That's a different problem You probably forgot the parens and that its `Select Min(Year)...` not `Select min year`. Its looking for a column name min which doesn't exist

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
SELECT     MIN(Price) AS Price, MIN(Year) AS Year
FROM         tblProduct
HAVING      (MIN(Price) IS NOT NULL) OR
                      (MIN(Price) <> '')
```

Comment: That would return 2005 for the year . The OP is looking for 2000

Comment: MIN ignores NULL, and an empty string is different than null, so this would most likely not work. Even if it did, it would select 0 instead of 200 so it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Vincent - Yup your right there that Min ignores null and empty strings, I stand to be corrected.  But it will still run and return the result as wanted I just checked it.

Comment: @Raymund: It doesn't ignore empty strings! Only NULL.

Comment: Dosent work, "" return on the min Price, The value is never NULL

Answer (score 0):

MIN, MAX, SUM, AVG and certain other aggregates will return NULL if a NULL exists in the data set. You want to use:

```
SELECT ISNULL(MIN(Price),0) as MinPrice, ISNULL(MIN(Year),0) as MinYear FROM tblProduct
```

Comment: That's not true, at least not for every RDBMS.

Comment: Good call, i was thinking specifically of MS SQL Server.